# Why fprintf() doesn't print anything even though the file exists and it's opened and closed correctly?

Tags: c, printf

It's my first exercise about Files and I have to write some code so that if I write a word in the console, it gets printed in the file. The program ends if I input the word "fine" (it's Italian for end). It seems like the file is opened and closed correctly, the program reads the inserted chars, but nonetheless, the file remains blank.

I tried opening the file in various modes, I tried printing how many chars were read, I even tried deleting the file (but it actually does't exit even if I added exit(1).

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
    FILE * fp;
    char s[64];
    if ((fp = fopen("prova.txt", "r+")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    do {
        scanf("%s", s);
        if (strcmp("fine", s) != 0) {
            fprintf(fp, "%s ", s);
        }
    } while (strcmp("fine", s) != 0);
    fclose (fp);
    return 0;
}
```

It should save all the words in a text file, but it remains blank.

Comment: @KBir nor writing only. reading is from stdin

Comment: How are you checking the contents of the file? *When* are you checking? Remember that output to files are by default *buffered*, nothing will be actually written unless you [flush](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) the stream (or fill up the buffer).

Comment: I didn't know I wasn't supposed to do that, I'm fairly new... What do I have to change?

Comment: Closing the file should also flush the buffer. You only need to do it manually if you are checking the file while the program is running.

Comment: Tested the code on [onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/SyE825MRN) and your code has properly written the words to the file. It should work. Except that you should check `scanf` return status, it looks ok.

Comment: the program works fine for me. So as already mentioned, prova.txt contains the words after the program has terminated succesfully

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I open the file after every run but it's blank. I just added flush(fp) but nothing has changed...

Comment: But why is the file still blank?

Comment: @lurker no I mean the file target of this code remains blank

Comment: @JohnnyMopp how do I do that?

Comment: Just make sure the program has exited before checking the file. Or call [`fflush(fp);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) after each call to `fprintf(fp, "%s ", s);`

Comment: If you run your program, and give the input `fine`, does the program end? Is the contents of the file changed after the program have *ended*?

Comment: Possibilities: **(a)** The copy of the file you're writing to isn't the one you're checking. The use of `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE` suggests Visual Studio, so  check the `Debug` and/or `Release` directories to see if the updated file is there (or, better yet, include a full path in the `fopen` call). **(b)** The tool you're viewing the file with doesn't like that there are no CRLF... try – at least temporarily – using `fprintf(fp, "%s\n", s);`.

Comment: Start adding printf() or use the debugger. Also, make sure you're checking the the file in the right place. Also, re-open the file for reading after you close it and see what your code sees there.

Comment: Can you check the return value of `fprintf` for errors? It should return the number of characters written on success, or a negative value on failure.

Comment: The `fclose` function could also return an error. `fclose` returns 0 on success or `EOF` on failure.

Comment: Post sample input used.

Comment: Sounds like a great time to use a debugger, and step through the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your program looks OK. Most likely, you are checking the wrong file.

An educated guess: you are using some IDE. If this is the case, the file *is* created, but is created somewhere else. To be sure, print the working directory (`man getcwd`) somewhere in the beginning of your program, and look for the file there.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use "w" to open a new file with write priviledges

change

`if ((fp = fopen("prova.txt", "r+")) == NULL) {`

with

`if ((fp = fopen("prova.txt", "w+")) == NULL) {`

EDIT: Maybe i didn't explained myself, r+ will fail if the file doesn't exist, changing it works for me

Comment: No. `r+` opens for read and write. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen `"r+" read extended Open a file for read/write`

Comment: that's right but OP states that open() works so we can assume it exists

Comment: If I could post a screenshot I would... the file exists because I deleted it and I created another one with the same name and it doesn't exit

Comment: well, it doesn't for me

Comment: I would think the OP would see their "Error" output if this were the case.